# Синтаксический разбор конструкции ДРУГ ДРУГУ

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

В выражении

> смотрели в глаза **друг другу**

словосочетание *друг другу* замещает позицию *дательного падежа*.

Вопросы:

1. Какой частью речи является слово *друг* в данном словосочетании?
2. В каком падеже употреблено слово *друг* в данном словосочетании?
3. Какой тип синтаксической связи реализуется в словосочетании *друг другу*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вопрос-то не простой...
Дело в том, что это сочетание надо отличать от конструкции "(один) друг ... (второго)  друга". Последнее нечасто, но может встретиться во фразе типа
*И другу всегда поможет друг,

Если друг в беде"*
(Из песни, не могу найти первоисточник.)

> 1. Какой частью речи является слово друг в данном словосочетании?
> 2. В каком падеже употреблено слово друг в данном словосочетании?

1-2  "Друг другу" устойчивое сочетание с абсолютно закрепленной внутренней связью (близкое к идиоме). Внутри такого сочетания части речи не выделяются, а падежи (и другие словоизменительные категории) не детерминируются. Само же словоизменение происходит в целом для сочетания, которое выступает как одушевленное существительное (даже если речь идет о неодушевленных объектах) множественного числа в роли дополнения. 
Интересно, что именительный падеж отсутствует: сочетание не может играть роль подлежащего.

И. -
Р. Избегают (кого?) друг друга
Д. Сообщают (кому?) друг другу
В. Любят (кого?) друг друга
Т. Гордятся (кем) друг другом
П. Помнят (о ком) друг (о) друге.

> Какой тип согласования реализуется в словосочетании друг другу?

У согласования нет "типа". Согласование - один из видов словосочетания, наряду с управлением и примыканием.

В неразделяемом словосочетании вид связи может и не дифференцироваться. В данном случае это, полагаю (хотя, может, меня и поправят), просто невозможно, поскольку имеет место внешнее по отношению к самому словосочетанию ***падежное управление***.

**UPD**

> Интересно было бы узнать как это словосочетание развивалось в
>   диахронии и какая изначально там была связь между словами.

Могу лишь предположить, что изначально "друга" (и прочее — во всех падежах) было не существительным, а краткой формой прилагательного "другой" (имевшей падежные формы, омонимичные современному существительному). То есть всё сочетание звучало в переводе на современный язык как "один другого". На эту же мысль наводят и аналогичные конструкции как в близкородственных славянских: *один одного* (укр.), *адзін аднаго* (бел.), *един от друг* (болг.), так и в совсем дальних *each other* (англ.) и даже *бие биенээ* (монгольский, дословно "каждый другому"), *ҳар як дигар* (тадж. — аналогично), *birbirleri* (турецкий, примерно то же) и (предположительно) что-то подобное — на иврите...

Так что о какой-то диахронии говорить не приходится, сама форма древнейшая и совершенно интернациональная. Она только наполняется в разных языках разными словами.

**UPD-2**

Я нашел текст песни, о которой говорил в самом начале.
Это "Песня о друге" из кинофильма "Путь к причалу", автор слов - Григорий Поженян. Куплет, который я процитировал, в фильм не вошел, отсюда и сложности при поиске.
Впрочем, в канонической версии есть строчка, не менее подходящая для такого примера.

Если радость на всех одна - на всех и беда одна;
В море встает за волной волна, а за спиной - спина.
Здесь, у самой кромки бортов, **друга прикроет друг**,
Друг всегда уступить готов место в шлюпке и круг.

Его не надо просить ни о чем, друг все поймет без слов.
Друг - это третье мое плечо, третье мое крыло.
А если случится, что он влюблен, а я на его пути;
Уйду с дороги, таков закон - третий должен уйти.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Интересно было бы узнать как это словосочетание развивалось в диахронии и какая изначально там была связь между словами.

Comment: Благодарю за интересное рассуждение о предположительном происхождении словосочетания. Очень интересно.